# NSManagedObject Validation and Subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode8, nsmanagedobject

How to implement custom property validation methods for `NSManagedObject` subclasses in Xcode 8.0 or above? How we can create an `NSManagedObject` subclasses in Xcode 8.0?

Before Xcode 8.0

> Xcode -> File -> New -> File -> Core Data -> NSManagedObject Subclass

Comment: You ask for Swift 3 and 4 ?

Comment: @Arrabidas92 Swift 3.0

Comment: Here is how through Apple documentation (Look for Creating NSManagedObject Subclasses) : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html

Comment: @Arrabidas92 No mate! I think it's not for Swift 3.0 or later. But thanks for your attention. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well I see at the bottom of the documentation : Updated 2017-03-27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Xcode 8 or higher, `NSManagedObject` subclasses are created automatically unless you tell Xcode to not do that. With Swift you can let Xcode create a subclass, or create your own subclass and let Xcode add an extension with attribute declarations, or tell Xcode to not automatically generate anything. It's not about Swift 3.0 or 4.0, it's about Xcode.

You choose one of these in the model editor. "Class Definition" is the default.

[image: Xcode managed object class generation]

Validation methods work the same as they ever did. You implement them in a managed object subclass. You can also implement them in an extension on that class.

Comment: What did you mean by saying **You can implement them in an extension on that class**. Can you explain by showing some sample code? I know how the *Automatic Subclass Generation* works. Thanks for your answer.!

Comment: I mean that if you have a subclass of NSManagrdObject, you can create a Swift extension to that class and implement the method in that extension.